# What is the Copyright of Posted Code on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, rules

Are the code posted on Stack Overflow open-source? As in, if I copy-paste a piece of code written by a user into production for commercial uses without asking permission, can the user sue me for copyright infringement?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=copying+code+stack+overflow+legal+site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/ [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12527) is probably the canonical

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Yes, but my god, someone needs to edit the title of that post. Very confusing.

Comment: @NoName Feel free to edit it...